# SmartGwt window header height

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, smartclient

Any idea how to change the **header height** of the **window** in smartGwt?

I tried increasing the font of the header contents and then auto setting height but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

i found the solution, all you have to do is redefine the attribute headerDefaults for your window class, it's a map, so you can proceed like this:

```
Map<String, Object> headerDefaults = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Integer newHeight = 64;
headerDefaults.put("height", newHeight);
mySmartGwtWindow.setAttribute("headerDefaults", headerDefaults, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any property enabling to change the header height. I've tried playing with the ***HeaderControl*** thinking I could add a dummy control an empty icon which height could be the one we look for but the height of the ***ControlIcon*** are fixed in the constructor to 15. So no more idea for tonight...